# How to sort an array of Strings that contain "m" first, everything else second

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

```
String[] strArray = {"xyz", "aaazzz","abc","mft","gh","j", "aaazaz", "mm", "am"};

Arrays.sort(strArray, Comparator.comparing((s) -> s.contains("m")));
System.out.println("Array sorted by 'm': " + Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

I have been able to get the array so that it is sorted using 'm', but the results are in defending order - as in all strings that contain 'm' are at the end.

My print out reads;

```
Array sorted by 'm': [xyz, aaazzz, abc, gh, j, aaazaz, mft, mm, am]
```

I have considered using indexOf() but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get this to work.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You can convert everything to ASCII or unicode numbers, mod by m so that m = 0 and then sort and convert back.

Comment: If two strings both contain "m", or both do not contain "m", how should they be sorted? Alphabetically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural order of `boolean` values is `false` -> `true` (i.e. `false` comes first).

You need to change the condition of your Comparator to get elements containing `m` to be placed and the beginning of the sorted list:

```
Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.contains("m"))
```

You might want both groups of string (with and without `m`) to be sorted as well. For that you can use method [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) which allow to build an aggregate Comparator based on several conditions:

```
Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.contains("m"))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

**Note** that when comparators are being chained together, the type inference mechanism fails to infer the types of arguments used in the chained methods based on the *target type* (i.e. the expected aggregate Comparator). And we need to either provide the types of argument in the lambda expression explicitly, like shown above `(String s) -> ...`, or use a so-called *type-witness* `<String, Boolean>comparing(...)`.